# Give class to li on the base of title?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My Html code is this:

```
  <li class="enabled _msddli_ selected" title="USA (+1)"><span class="ddlabel"
   style="color: black;">USA (+1)</span><p class="hidlable">USA (+1)</p>
    <div class="clear"></div></li>

 <li class="enabled _msddli_ " title="UK (+1)">
 <span class="ddlabel" style="color: black;">UK (+1)</span>
 <p class="hidlable">USA (+1)</p><div class="clear"></div></li>
```

I want to give class `selected` to `li` on the base of `title` attribute. 
ie `li` having `title` "UK (+1)" should given  `selected` class.

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use **[Attribute Equals Selector [name=”value”]](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)**:

```
$('li[title="UK (+1)"]').addClass('selected ')
```

Comment: @PrashantSharma glad it helps :)